# How to download HD Youtube video on iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube

There are many, Free or Paid iOS Apps to download Youtube Video. Most of them worked the same, where you paste the URL into the built in browsers, press and hold the play button to download.

However most of these Apps only download the low / 360P version of the file. I wanted to save the full 720P or 1080P video, and have yet to find an Apps that does it. Anyone know of any Apps/ Ways to download the Youtube HD video on iPhone?

Edit: I try using KeepVid.com, the resulted link only allows me to play the video file in Safari, and not save it.

Comment: You can use QuickTime player to record whatever is on your iPhone in HD, that's how I save YouTube videos.

Answer (score 2):

iCab Mobile (http://www.icab-mobile.de/) is a very functional web browser with many plugins In addition to the ability to download files for local storage and then opening with other apps via iOS's native share sheets. If you can view the video in the browser, you can download it. It also offers the ability to change your browser's ID so that you can tell the server you are on a Mac or Windows desktop in order to get your desired resolution. Highly recommended tool for downloading videos at whatever resolution you want.

Answer (score 0):

Um volle 720P oder 1080P Videos zu speichern, können Sie [StreamFab Youtube Downloder](https://streamfab.de/youtube-video-downloader.htm) verwenden.
Dieser Downloader kann Videos in 4K/8K-Auflösung herunterladen. Sie können diese Videos auf Ihrem iPhone ansehen. Dies hängt jedoch von der Auflösung des Originalvideos ab.

Edit for English Translation:
To save full 720P or 1080P videos, you can use StreamFab Youtube Downloder. This downloader can download videos in 4K/8K resolution. You can watch these videos on your iPhone. However, this depends on the resolution of the original video.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please note that the site is primarily English language speaking, so as a courtesy to you I've edited in an English translation, to the best of Google's ability. Please note that for future posts, if English isn't your primary language you can also do the same. You'll have more engagement with other users that way. BTW, please also indicate whether you are affiliated with the site / product in any way, otherwise someone might flag the answer as spam.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't necessarily need an app, there are much better web pages out there for downloading YT videos. Try this: https://loader.to/en22/